# htaccess causing problems with python cgi

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I have two pages:

http://arbsq.net/canvas/index.htm

http://arbsq.net/canvas/index.py

When I want to make the address http://arbsq.net/canvas automatically redirtect to index.py, I use the following htaccess:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 index.htm index.py
```

but it keeps causing the obscure 500 Internal server error if I use any of the addresses:

http://arbsq.net/canvas

http://arbsq.net/canvas/index.htm

http://arbsq.net/canvas/index.py

I checked all other possible problems (file permission..etc), and I am lmost sure it is the htaccess...Any idea what can the problem be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want make the address `http://arbsq.net/canvas` automatically load `index.py` then you better use `DirectoryIndex` like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.py index.htm
```

This basically loads `index.py` if found in a directory otherwise it will try to load `index.htm`.

Don't forget to remove your `Redirect 301` rule.